# tfx.orchestration.experimental has no attribute 'get_default_kubeflow_metadata_config'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow, tfx

I am trying to orchestrate a TFX pipeline using kubeflow and I am getting the following error during the creation of the pipeline.

`AttributeError: module 'tfx.orchestration.experimental' has no attribute 'get_default_kubeflow_metadata_config'`

Below is my code for my pipeline runner file:

```
from tfx import v1 as tfx
import my_config
import my_pipeline1
from tfx.orchestration import experimental

def run():
  """Define a kubeflow pipeline."""

  metadata_config = experimental.get_default_kubeflow_metadata_config(
  )

  runner_config = experimental.KubeflowDagRunnerConfig(
      kubeflow_metadata_config=metadata_config,
      tfx_image=my_config.PIPELINE_IMAGE)

  experimental.KubeflowDagRunner(
      config=runner_config
  ).run(
      my_pipeline1.create_pipeline(
          pipeline_name=my_config.PIPELINE_NAME,
          pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
          data_root=DATA_PATH,
          preprocessing_fn = my_config.PREPROCESSING_FN, 
          run_fn = my_config.RUN_FN,
      ))
if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.set_verbosity(logging.INFO)
  run()
```

Please let me know if there is a fix to this problem. I am currently using TFX 1.0.0. Thanks in advance.